# How to get current wallpaper uri in Android?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I want to get the current wallpaper uri , I have no idea .
It seems that WallpaperManager or `wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo()` has not such method to get uri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't see a way to get the URI, but you can get the drawable itself it seems using these methods:

- [getDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDrawable%28%29)
- [getFastDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getFastDrawable%28%29)
- [peekDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#peekDrawable%28%29)
- [peekFastDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#peekFastDrawable%28%29)